# A pattern to be designed using template binding of knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

We have a situation as mentioned below:

There is a set of data for a search panel, it's called in several pages with different types of components and placement of it. There can be combo boxes, radio buttons, input boxes and buttons.

Knockout has a feature of template binding in which we can have the flexibility to show numerous panels on condition using a template in the html mapped to MOdel.

Below is the code and pattern:

### HTML:

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div>
        <table class="data-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4"> Search </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: preSearchData" >
                <tr>
                    <!-- ko template: { name: 'label_' + templateName()} -->
                    <!-- /ko -->

                </tr>               
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/html" id="label_Combo">
    <td>It is a Combo </td>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="label_Number">
    <td>
       It is a Number
    </td>
</script>
```

### MODEL:

```
Models.Components = function(data) {

            var self = this;
            self.number = data.number;
            self.labelCd = data.labelCd;
            self.xmlTag = data.xmlTag;
            self.Type = new Cobalt.Models.Type(data.Type);

        };

        Models.Type = function(data) {

            var self = this;
            self.component = data.component;
            self.records = data.records;
            self.minLength = data.minLength;
            self.maxLength = data.maxLength;
            self.defaultValue = data.defaultValue;
            self.targetAction = data.targetAction;

        };
Models.ComponentType = function (paymentTypeCode, data, actionId) {

            var ret;
self.templateName(data.component);
            if (!data || (actionId === Cobalt.Constant.Dashboard.copyProfile))
                data = {};

            if (paymentTypeCode == Cobalt.Constant.Dashboard.creditCard)
                ret = new Cobalt.Models.CreditCardPaymentType(data.cardHolderName, data.cardNumber, data.cardExpireDate);

            else if (paymentTypeCode == Cobalt.Constant.Dashboard.dd)
                ret = new Cobalt.Models.DDPaymentType(data.pinNumber);

            else if (Cobalt.Utilities.startsWith(paymentTypeCode, Cobalt.Constant.Dashboard.yahooWallet)) {
                if (!data && paymentTypeCode.indexOf('~') > -1) {
                    data.payCode = paymentTypeCode.substr(paymentTypeCode.indexOf('~') + 1, paymentTypeCode.lastIndexOf('~'));
                    data.billingAgentId = paymentTypeCode.substr(paymentTypeCode.lastIndexOf('~') + 1);
                }

                ret = new Cobalt.Models.WalletPaymentType(data.payCode, data.billingAgentId);
            }
            else if (paymentTypeCode == Cobalt.Constant.Dashboard.ajl) {
                ret = new Cobalt.Models.DDPaymentType(data.pinNumber);
            }

            else
                ret = data || {};

            return ret;
        };

Models.POCModel = function () {
            var self = this;
             self.templateName = ko.observable();
            self.preSearchData = ko.observableArray([]);

            self.getResultData = function () {
                var data = Cobalt.Data.getResultData();
                var componentList = data.componentList;


                self.preSearchData(componentList);
            };
        };
```

Above code gives me a error saying:

> **Ajax error: parsererror ( Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: templateName is not defined; Bindings value: template:
>   { name: 'label_' + templateName()}  ) cobalt.init.js:66**

Comment: Sorry I don't understand - what is the problem that you are having?  Is it that you are getting the error from Ajax or something related to a new design pattern?

Comment: How are you binding to your page? It seems as though your foreach: preSearchData is not using the object 'Models.POCModel' which is the only object type you've got templateName defined.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but it shows an alternate way of doing this using the ViewModel type to find the view (Template)

http://jsfiddle.net/nmLsL/2

Each type of editor is a ViewModel

```
MyApp.Editors.BoolViewModel = function(data) {
    this.checked = data;
};
MyApp.Editors.BoolViewModel.can = function(data) {
    return typeof data === "boolean";
};
```

And it has a can function that determins if it can edit the value

I then usea library called Knockout.BindingConventions to find the template connected to the ViewModel

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.BindingConventions/wiki/Template-convention

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach` binding creates a child binding context, which doesn't include `templateName` since that's part of the parent. Replace it with

```
<!-- ko template: { name: 'label_' + $parent.templateName()} -->
```